# How to set up a github project with Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iOS Application and am using github for the first time, there is a project in the github and i would like to import it to my computer, what are the steps please to do this ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Project from github below screen shot ...!

[image]

after extract the zip and open the xcode project file...!